# detect if embed youtube video down on my webpage

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api

If I embed youtube video on my webpage, is it possible to use jquery/javascript detect the video is down(due to copyright or user close the video)?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the video data with javascript using YouTube Data API v3:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

You can check if the video exist, trying to retrieve the video data:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

and after retrieve the video data you can validate the following fields:

```
contentDetails.regionRestriction

The regionRestriction object contains information about the countries where a video is (or is not) viewable. The object will contain either the contentDetails.regionRestriction.allowed property or the contentDetails.regionRestriction.blocked property.

contentDetails.regionRestriction.allowed[]

A list of region codes that identify countries where the video is viewable. If this property is present and a country is not listed in its value, then the video is blocked from appearing in that country. If this property is present and contains an empty list, the video is blocked in all countries.

contentDetails.regionRestriction.blocked[]

A list of region codes that identify countries where the video is blocked. If this property is present and a country is not listed in its value, then the video is viewable in that country. If this property is present and contains an empty list, the video is viewable in all countries.
```